# Indefinite article before "increased emphasis"?

Tags: indefinite-article, zero-article

The question is whether the indefinite article *an* before "increased emphasis" is needed.

> During system design, there is increased emphasis on interface-based design.
>
> During system design, there is an increased emphasis on interface-based design.

Are both sentences correct?

Answer (score 2):

Both versions are fine - they mean exactly the same, and are [about equally common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%20is%20increased%20emphasis,there%20is%20an%20increased%20emphasis&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)..

[image]

Note that if we replace *emphasis on interface-based design* with, say, *tendency to focus on the interface*, we ***need*** the article. It's also [much more likely](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%20is%20emphasis%20on,there%20is%20an%20emphasis%20on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) to be included if we discard the (arguably redundant) word *increased*, so it's probably easiest to always use **an** in such constructions.